# Does DNS works for 2 URLs which are pointed to 2 different ports

Tags: url, dns, port-number

I do have a Qlik Nprinting application in Azure VM which has 2 web portals running on different ports. In our project, we have configured port numbers for web portals to 443 and 8443. URLs to access the web portals will be `https://IPaddress:443/` and `https://IPaddress:8443/`. Both the URLs are working fine. After that, we have provided a DNS (`clientx.intranet.example.com`) to the IP of VM.

Now the links to web portals with DNS will be - `https://clientx.intranet.example.com:443/` and `https://clientx.intranet.example.com:8443/`.
The URL `https://clientx.intranet.example.com:443/` is working fine without any issues. But the URL `https://clientx.intranet.example.com:8443/` is throwing an error "The proxy server is not responding". Struggling to solve this issue from past 1 week. What do I need to do to make the other URL with DNS work.

Comment: Have you verified using DNS lookup tools that the DNS is pointing to the IP address?

Comment: Yes, I have verified. DNS is pointing to the IP address. As mentioned the URL DNS with 443 is working and taking to the right web portal. But URL DNS with 8443 is not working and throwing an error "The proxy server is not responding" So I guess it may not be DNS pointing issue. There is no 8443 port issue too as  URL with IP address and 8443 is working fine. Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a proxy server, CDN, or load balancer involved to your knowledge?

Comment: If the name resolution is working (then it is no more a DNS problem, hence you can remove that tag), "The proxy server is not responding" may be because a firewall in the path or on the proxy host does not let access to port 8443...

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - To my knowledge, our team is not aware of proxy server/CDN/load balancer. Need to check with my DNS team on this.